# view pager with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to get the position of it, to use it in a class apart in Android.

class method is declared

```
public class Adaptador extends BaseAdapter {
```

and Method

```
 @Override
public View getView(*int position*, View convertirView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (null == convertirView) {
        view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(mResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        assert view != null;
        holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        view = convertirView;
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    bindView(holder, position);
    return view;
}
```

I want to get the position of this method.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean: position of a method?

Answer (score 0):

```
viewpager.setOnPageChangedListener(new OnPageChangedListener() {
         @Override
         public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

         }
         @Override
         public void onPageSelected(int position) {
          // position is your current position
         }
         @Override
         public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

         }
});
```